# How to remove a file with special characterictics

Tags: linux, terminal, rm

Hi I just created a file by mistake, doing a tar actually, anyway the problem I have is that I can't remove that file. It is called `--exclude-tag-under=hey.txt`

I am trying to use `rm -rf` command but it doesn't do the trick. this is the output

```
[root]# rm -rf '--exclude-tag-under\=hey.txt'
rm: unrecognized option '--exclude-tag-under\=hey.txt'
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

the problem here is that the command rm is recognizing the file as a flag and thats a problem, I've tried also

```
rm -rf *hey.txt
```

but it doesnt work neither

I've also tried to change the name of the file but its the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepend `./` like this: `rm ./--exclude-tag-under\=hey.txt`

When in doubt, check the man pages.
Running `man rm` will give you the rm man page, which, on Linux and OpenBSD (the ones I have tested) at least, will have a section saying:

> To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', use
>   one of these commands:
>
> rm -- -foo
>
> rm ./-foo

Comment: Done. sorry I'm new here

Answer (score 0):

Use `rm -- --exclude-tag-under=hey.txt`

```
$ ls
--exclude-tag-under=hey.txt
test
$ rm -- --exclude-tag-under=hey.txt
$ ls
test
```